# Sequences convergence in topological space of power set of rationals

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau = P(\mathbb{Q}) \cup \{ \mathbb{R} \} $. Show that $X = (\mathbb{R}, \tau)$ is a topological space. What does the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ converge to? Which sequences converge to $0$? What about $\sqrt{2}$?

I have successfully proved that $X$ is a topological space but I am confused about the convergences. We have defined that $x_n \to x$ means $\forall_{U \ni x} U \text{ open } \exists_{N}\forall_{n\geq N} x_n \in U$. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Note that the definition of $\tau$ should be written as $P(\mathbb{Q})\cup \{\mathbb{R}\}$. The sequence $1/n$ can't converge to a rational because each rational $r$ has the neighborhood $\{r\}$, which won't contain many elements of $1/n$. But for irrationals the only neighborhood that they have is $\mathbb{R}$, which contains the entire sequence.

Comment: To converge to a rational $r$ a sequence will have to really get into the neighborhood $\{r\}$. This gives that only the sequences that are eventually constant equal to $r$ are the only ones converging to $r$. In particular, when $r=0$, the sequences need to vanish eventually. For $\sqrt{2}$, any sequence converge to $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: So, $\frac{1}{n}$ does not converge at all?

Comment: It converges, to all irrational numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clearly a topological space as the powerset of the rationals is closed under intersections and unions and adding $\mathbb{R}$ to a union makes the union $\mathbb{R}$ and ading it to some finite intersection has no effect; so all axioms of topology are easy to check.

If $x$ is irrational (so almost all points of $\mathbb{R}$) it has only **one** (open) neighbourhood, namely $\Bbb R$, so **any** sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converges to $x$.

If $x$ is rational, $\{x\}$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ so a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ iff there is some index $N$ such that $x_n = x$ for $n \ge N$.

So your sequence $(\frac{1}{n})$ which is *not* eventually constant converges to **every** irrational $x$ (so to $\pi, \sqrt{2}, e^4$ etc...) and to no rational.

Comment: A difficulty for students is that "converges to" has a different meaning in general topology than in elementary analysis.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet It's the same definition though.